# Unable to locate the model you have specified: model_users

Tags: php, codeigniter

this is the my model code

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Model_users extends CI_Model() {

    public function can_log_in(){

        $this->db->where('email',$this->input->post('email'));
        $this->db->where('password',md5($this->input->post('password')));

        $query = $this->db->get('users');

        if($query->num_rows()==1){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    }
}

?>
```

this is code of controller

```
public function validate_credentials(){
    $this->load->model('model_users');

     if($this->model_users->can_log_in()){
        return true;
     } else {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('validate_credentials','Incorrect username/password');
        return false;
     }
}
```

Comment: Please describe your problem, and ask an actual question (with a question mark at the end).

Comment: Please make sure you are saving `*_model.php` in right folder (application/models/), as far as I tested its not case sensitive as @Bibhas suggested.

Comment: what is the model file name?

Comment: thanks mr  kumar_v and   Kyslik. i had missed .php extension in model file name...

Answer (score 1):

You model name is `Model_users` and your are loading `model_users`. Read [the documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html) carefully.

Comment: I load all my models, with no capital letter and it always works. As I just tested I tried changing also capital letter in folder structure (Capital_model.php) and it did load also.

Comment: @kyslik following the doc would ensure that nothing unexpected happens. That's my suggestion. As the doc says "Class names must have the first letter capitalized with the rest of the name lowercase." if not follow it, why have the doc?

Comment: I've read the doc and all but this does not solve OP problem (I guess), my bet is on wrong __file name__ vs __class name__ (not matching). As you can see he also commented that he had problem with his filename.